# current loop transmitter with higher regulated voltage

Tags: current, voltage-regulator

I have a xtr115 in my circuit that is used for 4-20mA current transmitter, the regulated voltage of xtr115 is +5V, but I need +12V and -12V in my circuit, is it possible to connect an external Regulator to XTR115 to build +12V without dependent on the output current?

Comment: Yes, you could do that with a switching supply, but the amount of available current will be very low and your supply must have exceptionally low quiescent current (not to mention your actual loads) so that you don't exceed the few mW available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can run the XTR115 from your +12 volt supply the answer is yes since it will work with 7.5 volts up to 24 volts (recommended maximum).

If you are asking can you generate a 12 volt supply from the internal 5 volt regulator of the XTR115, that would not be the best choice due to current limitations. You would be better to add a buck/boost regulator off of whatever is the voltage supply to the XTR115.